# How to make a responsive footer using media queries

Tags: html, css

I have a footer with 5 boxes:one for the logo,about,services,company and contact.
Below is the html code.

```
<footer class="mainfooter">
    <div class="footerlogo">
        <i class="fa fa-fax fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutbox">    
        <strong><p>ABOUT</p></strong>
        <p style="color:#ffffe6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, dicta, nisi id ullam debitis, obcaecati modi magni culpa quasi blanditiis similique !</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services"> 
        <ul>
            <li><strong><p>SERVICES</p></strong></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Financial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Medical</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Insurance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="company">
        <ul> 
            <li><strong><p>COMPANY</p></strong></li>     
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">          
        <ul>
            <li><strong><p>CONTACT</p></strong></li>                   
            <li style="color:#ffffe6"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> +27 000 0004l</li>
            <li style="color:#ffffe6"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> info@nevex.co.za</li>
            <li style="color:#ffffe6"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 Street. Cape Town. 8000</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="clearfix"></div>         
</footer>
```

I used media queries on the attempt that you can see below but it does not work

```
@media(max-width: 600px){
    .footerlogo, .about, .services, .contact, .company{
        display:block;
        color:black; 
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
    } 
}
```

How can I make the boxes go underneath each other in small devices?

Comment: They will already go on top of each other. The **only** reason that they won't, is that somewhere else you've specified that they shouldn't – for instance: `float:left` or `width:20%`. Try adding a `float:none;` and `width:100%` and it should start to get closer. If  you post an actual demo, someone may be able to help more

Comment: for me all sections are under each other..what else you need?

Comment: You are actualy right Djave. I used floats out of the media queries so display:block would never work and obviously I change the width to 100%.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:
The class name for `about` is wrong. It should be `aboutbox` in CSS.
Change your media query defination to this `@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)`

These should solve your issue. 
For simplicity, I have reduced the width of divs to 50% in fiddle. You can still keep it as it is.

for further help, go through the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/wjb3prmf/

Comment: Indeed it works. Just had to change the min-width to max-width cause its to respond to all devices with width less than 600px.

Just found strange that the boxes are no aligned properly even with the padding and margin set to 0.
If you see from your snippet, the about box is far back to the left comparing to the other boxes below.
How can I align it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested you'r code, and it works fine. But cange your "about" class name.
In html you have `class="aboutbox"` and in css you used the `class="about"`. I think the problem is somewhere else, the code that you posted looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `!important` behind your properties may do the job.
Just like this;

```
@media(max-width: 600px){
    .footerlogo, .about, .services, .contact, .company{
        display:block !important;
        color:black !important; 
        padding:0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    } 
}
```